# Catty: A mini cat clone in Rust

Tags: console, rust

As part of my journey in learning the Rust programming language, I decided to make a miniature cat clone (catty) in it. The following is my code, which depends on [clap](https://clap.rs/) for argument parsing (see below). It currently only supports concatenating 1 file with possibly numbered lines (`-n/--number`). I tried to be as close as possible to the actual `cat` program for this:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate clap;

use std::{io, error, env, fs::read_to_string, path::PathBuf, process};

fn main() {
    process::exit(
        if let Err(err) = cli(env::args().collect::<Vec<_>>()) {
            // CLI parsing errors
            if let Some(clap_err) = err.downcast_ref::<clap::Error>() {
                eprint!("{}", clap_err);
            } else {
                eprintln!("{}", err);
            }
            1
        } else {
            0
        }
    );
}

fn cli(cli_args: Vec<String>) -> Result<(), Box<error::Error>> {
    let matches = clap::App::new("catty")
        .version(crate_version!())
        .about("A minimal clone of the linux utility cat.")
        .arg(clap::Arg::with_name("FILE")
            .help("The file to concatenate to standard output")
            .required(true))
        .arg(clap::Arg::with_name("number")
            .short("n")
            .long("number")
            .help("Numbers all output lines"))
        .get_matches_from_safe(cli_args)?;

    let file_contents = get_file_contents(matches.value_of("FILE").unwrap())?;
    let file_contents: Vec<&str> = file_contents.split("\n").collect();

    let number_lines = matches.is_present("number");

    for (i, line) in file_contents.iter().enumerate() {
        let formatted_line = if number_lines {
            format!("{:>6}  {}", i + 1, line)
        } else {
            line.to_string()
        };

        if i == file_contents.len() - 1 && line.len() > 0 {
            print!("{}", formatted_line);
        } else if !(i == file_contents.len() - 1 && line.len() == 0) {
            println!("{}", formatted_line);
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn get_file_contents(passed_argument: &str) -> Result<String, Box<error::Error>> {
    let mut resolved_path = PathBuf::from(passed_argument);

    if !resolved_path.exists() || !resolved_path.is_file() {
        resolved_path = PathBuf::from(env::current_dir()?);
        resolved_path.push(passed_argument);

        if !resolved_path.exists() || !resolved_path.is_file() {
            return Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotFound, "The passed file is either not a file or does not exist!").into());
        }
    }

    Ok(read_to_string(resolved_path)?)
}
```

My `Cargo.toml` is as follows:

```
[package]
name = "catty"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["My Name <my@email.com>"]

[dependencies]

[dependencies.clap]
version = "2.32"
default-features = false
features = ["suggestions"]
```

Here is what I want to know from this code review:

1. Is my code idiomatic rust (i.e good error handling, not overly verbose, etc)?
2. Is my code performant or can it be improved in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4: `use std::{env, error, fs::read_to_string, io, path::PathBuf, process};`

Just a personal taste, but I would do

```
use std::{env, error, io, process};
use std::fs::read_to_string;
use std::path::PathBuf;
```

Yes, nested includes are nice and easy, but hard to extend. It's up to you.

---

35: `let file_contents: Vec<&str> = file_contents.split('\n').collect();`

I would suggest using [`lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) instead.

Also, you can omit `&str` or change the line completly.

Either

```
let file_contents: Vec<_> = file_contents.lines().collect();
```

or

```
let file_contents = file_contents.lines().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

---

46/48: `line.len() > 0` / `line.len() == 0`

Replace that by `!line.is_empty()` and `line.is_empty()`.

---

60: `resolved_path = PathBuf::from(env::current_dir()?);`

Remove `PathBuf::from` completly, because [`current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.current_dir.html) is already a `PathBuf`

Comment: Also, is there an equivalent of `enumerate` for an iterator (so I can avoid collecting into a vector)?

Comment: Yes, you can call `enumerate` on every iterator. The thing is, that you don't know the length of your iterator, which is the reason why I didn't mentioned it. If you are willing to use `println!` every iteration, you can simplify your code/loop a lot.